# Android Pushwoosh custom data

Tags: java, android, eclipse, push-notification, pushwoosh

I done integrating pushwoosh according to pushwoosh guide to my Android app but I need to customize the data comes from the notification. I've paid for custom data and i'm sending a json like this

{"category":"Iraq","id":"1000"}

so when the application get the notification can do an event according to this custom data from pushwoosh.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on the Android sample:
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-sdk-samples/blob/master/Native/Android/src/com/pushwoosh/test/tags/sample/app/MainActivity.java

public void doOnMessageReceive(String message)

JSONObject customJson = new JSONObject(messageJson.getString("u"));

The custom data will be under "u" parameter in the push payload.

Comment: I integrated also this Service, yet i have configured my menifest only. and i am receiving notification. But what i want to do is "Store the data comes in notification" I tried using Broadcast receiver but couldn't. I can save the data only when the activity contains [this code](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/native-android-sdk) how can i store the data even when i am out of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Shader the URL you have mentioned is giving 404 . I guess this is the more relevant URL . Please confirm and update your answer

https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-native-samples/tree/master/Android

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the repo structure has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

The sample project was moved to SDK. you can find it here:

https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-android-sdk